# How to make an autoplay inline video to fullscreen on landscape RN (IOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video

I make a project with React Native for both platforms (Android & IOS) that in the first page and the pages of posts are videos who playing automatic.This video sometimes is youtube and sometimes m3u8.
On portrait orientation i want to play inline with some content beneath and on landscape i want to play fullscreen.

I use react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video for manipulate WebView component and for Android it works. But as the name says it works only for android. I wants the similar behaviour for IOS too.
I try react-native-af-video-player but when i setup the dependency react-native-orientation the video stuck in fullscreen mode. Also the react-native-af-video-player is for mp4 only player.

```
 if(livestream.type === 'youtube' && Platform.OS === 'android') {
            the_live_video = (
                <WebView
                    style={{ width: VIDEO_WIDTH, height: VIDEO_HEIGHT, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    javaScriptEnabled
                    source={{
                    uri: livestream.url
                }}
                />
            ) 
        } else if(livestream.type === 'youtube' && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            the_live_video = (
                <WebView
                    style={{ width: VIDEO_WIDTH, height: VIDEO_HEIGHT, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    javaScriptEnabled
                    source={{
                    uri: livestream.url
                }}
                />
            ) 

        } else if(livestream.type === 'jwplayer' && Platform.OS === 'android') { 
            the_live_video = (
                <WebView
                    style={{ width: VIDEO_WIDTH, height: VIDEO_HEIGHT, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    javaScriptEnabled
                    source={{
                    uri: livestream.url
                }}
                />
            ) 
        } else if(livestream.type === 'jwplayer' && Platform.OS === 'ios') {

            const video = {
                html: `<video width="${VIDEO_WIDTH}" height="${VIDEO_HEIGHT}"  controls  src="${
                    livestream.url
                }"></video>`
            };
            the_live_video = (
                <WebView
                    style={{ width: VIDEO_WIDTH, height: VIDEO_HEIGHT, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    javaScriptEnabled
                    source={video}
                />
            ) 

        }
```

As i said i want the behaviour of react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video for IOS platform too.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-af-video-player is no longer maintained as a result it is causing a lot of trouble you can use [react-native-af-video-player-updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-af-video-player-updated) package in place.